# Validate Form function containing Ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, onsubmit

I finally got my Ajax function to work properly but now I have another program.  My validate form functions seems to be returning before the Ajax complete.  If open my console log, the console.log(result);right before my return result; prints out before my console.log(resp);found in the success function.  so my validate form is continuing to return false and thus my form is not submitting.  But I know my success is hitting because I see it dump in the console log.  Why would this be?  Do I need to wrap my function with document ready or something?

Below is my code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
function validateForm(){
  var email = document.forms["signupform"]["email"].value;
  var result = false;
  if (email != ""){
    $.ajax({           
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/CheckEmail2.php",  
      data: { "User_Email": email },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
        if(resp.reply == "Not Found"){
          result = true;
          return result;
        }
        else
        {
        result = false;
        return result;
        }

      },
      //error: function(data, status){
        //console.log(data, status);
        //alert("error");
      //}
    }); //end Ajax
  }
  console.log(result);
  return result;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please show us where you're referencing this function?

Comment: here is my form tag.  <form name="signupform" method="post" class="form-container card_style" action="/register_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that ajax is asynchronous so the retrun to the function occurs long before the ajax completes.

You can use the native submit of the form element inside the success and use a flag to bypass the ajax

```
var isValid = false
function validateForm(){
  var form = document.forms["signupform"]
  var email = form["email"].value;

  if (email != "" && !isValid){
    $.ajax({           
      type: "POST",  
      url: "/CheckEmail2.php",  
      data: { "User_Email": email },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(resp){
        isValid = true
        // submit the form
        form.submit()
      }
    }); //end Ajax
  }

  return isValid ;
};
```